# UIView w/UITextView that moves with UIScrollView's dismiss interactive

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

I've searched for this issue and have found bits & pieces but not a real duplicate.

I am attempting to create a UITextView, that's encapsulated within a UIView that will dynamically change it's height based on it's content, this is solved easily enough with auto layout and by disabling scrolling on the UITextView.

I would then like the UITextView to move, interactively, with a keyboard that may or may not dismiss (via setting the dismiss interactively property on a UIScrollView).

This overall behavior would mimic how the text input works on iOS Messages - it pretty much scrolls nicely with an interactive dismissing keyboard AND grows in height when needed.

My attempt thus far has been to create a UITableView that takes up the entire view, and another view that will encapsulate the text view, it's constrained horizontally and pinned to the bottom of the view controller's view. The height is left out but auto layout can determine the size intrinsically through the UITextView within in it.

As shown:

[image]

This works so far so good while in the simulator without spawning the keyboard:

[image]

Now, in an attempt to get the encapsulating view to be pinned to the keyboard I've attempted to use it as the input accessory view on the view controller, in order to do so, I must first remove it from the view controller's view hierarchy. I'm not sure exactly where to do this (keyboard will show notification, text view should begin editing delegate, etc?) As everything I've attempted so far has resulted in the view being missing as an accessory view for the keyboard (if the keyboard does indeed show).

Like this:

[image]

From:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var inputTextview: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var genericInputContainer: UIView!

    // MARK: - Properites
    fileprivate var shouldAddInputContainerAsAccessory = false
    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        if shouldAddInputContainerAsAccessory {
            return genericInputContainer
        }
        return nil
    }

    // MARK: - Actions
    @objc fileprivate func keyboardWillShow(sender: Notification) {
    }

    fileprivate func observeNotifications() {
        let keyboardWillShowAction = #selector(keyboardWillShow(sender:))
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: keyboardWillShowAction,
            name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow,
            object: nil)
    }

    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        observeNotifications()
        inputTextview.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
        genericInputContainer.removeFromSuperview()
        shouldAddInputContainerAsAccessory = true
        return true
    }

    func textViewShouldEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
        shouldAddInputContainerAsAccessory = false
        return true
    }
}
```

I am hesitant to try creating a new view from the view that already exists because I will be adding several different animations/ transforms to elements within the encapsulating view (next to the text view).

Comment: I would make the view with the text field the `inputAccessoryView` of the view controller's view, then make the view controller's view the first responder in `viewDidAppear`.  You'd have to subclass `UIView` to return `true` from `canBecomeFirstResponder` then set the view controller's root view's class to your subclass in the storyboard.  You wouldn't add the view with the text field added to your view hierarchy at all if you did it this way since the system would add it itself when the view became the first responder.

Comment: @Fred did you end up finding a solution to this? I'm in the same boat.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the input and then assigning it to your keyboard accessory, use the keyboard observer to get the height of the keyboard when it appears and then adjust the bottom constraint of the text input.  You can get the keyboard height like this:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        self.keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height
        //debugPrint(keyboardHeight)
    }
}
```

Comment: The notification, nor any that I'm aware of, is fired along with a keyboard as it is being dismissed interactively (where it can move up and down and may not dismiss at all).

Comment: This would be the func you assign to the UIKeyboardWillShow observer. You can also assign a func to the UIKeyboardWillHide observer to reset the bottom constraint when the keyboard hides.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding the dismiss interactive behavior, a user can move the keyboard up and down by dragging on a scroll view, and at such time, i would like my input view to be moved along with it.

Comment: I don't think you can scroll the keyboard itself. I think that is a custom animation that is only available to Apple.

Comment: I'm not trying to scroll the keyboard itself, the keyboard is controlled by iOS, but an accessory input view is taken along with it.

Comment: I'm asking how to take a storyboard UIView w/UITextView and use it as an accessory input view